# Голосовые звонки socket.io

Tags: node.js, angular2, socket.io, чат

В чат нужно добавить возможность голосовых звонков. Проект на Node.js/Socket.io/Angular2. Какие для этого есть библиотеки и как вообще это можно реализовать?

Comment: Тут скорее WebRTC надо припаивать.

Comment: [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js) - рекомендую. Еще google тоже хороший сервис, помогает в таких вопросах. Своими силами webRTC припаивать - это та еще боль.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, как это работает.

SocketIo состоит из 2х частей.

[Первая часть](https://socket.io/docs/) - это серверная часть. Подключается к ноде.

Вторая часть - клиентская (всё та же ссылка на доку, что и в первой части).

[Третья часть](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-socket-io) - использование модуля ng-socket-io для angular2,4

---

*Если Вы впервые сталкиваетесь с веб-сокетами, то советую почитать [вводную тему](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets)*

---

Для начала установить socketIO на сервер.

```
npm install socket.io
```

И напишите код на ноде как в [примере](https://socket.io/docs/)

Тут важно отметить то, что сокеты отрабатывают по событиям, то есть никак в аяксе один урл одно действие.

Что касается клиента, создайте страницу для него и напишите код, аналогичный  [доки](https://socket.io/docs/), только для клиента.

Вы можете создавать свои события и подписываться на них на сервере.

Что касается ng-socket-io, я его не использовал и не знаю насколько он хорошо работает с Angular2 или 4.

Для проверки соединения/работтоспособности сокетов используйте вкладку `network->ws`

Comment: А причем тут голосовые звонки?

Comment: @Alexandr точно, спасибо, я как то не то написал, чёт подумал что чат нужно